# Is it possible to use a locally hosted application on a page tab application during development?

Tags: facebook

I want to be able to display my application in an iframe via a page tab on someone's profile, I have a local version of my application running with SSL (although it is a self assigned certificate), on `https://localhost:443`.

When I set this url as the canvas url for the canvas page it works correctly, but as a page tab nothing is displayed. In fact upon inspecting the html where I believe the iframe should be there isn't even an iframe, and no actual request is being made to my application.

Does facebook make the request to the page tab url from their servers or something?? (as this would obviously mean you couldn't use a local version of your app). Or does it something to do with the markup my app is returning, as people on the net seem to be saying that you cannot return `<html>`, `<body>` or `<head>` tags to a page tab application.

Help. Please.

[image: here is an image of my settings page for the app]

Comment: "Canvas URL" and "Page Tab URL" isn't the same, are you sure you have configured both in Application Settings?

Comment: I know they are not the same, and I have configured both to the url: https://localhost:443/, when I view the canvas page it displays the html from my local application, but when I view the application from a page tab nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible by configuring "Page Tab URL" and "Secure Page Tab URL" in the application settings.

Once application is visited (both canvas and page tab) Facebook issuing `POST` request to your app, but it's still made by the User's browser.

**Update:**
This seems like a bug on Facebook end, if you'll visit your application page tab while browsing Facebook over `HTTPS` it'll work, but if you not using "Secure Facebook" the canvas isn't even requested. As a solution for development you can use Facebook over `HTTPS` or use `HTTP` version as "Page Tab URL".

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the settings page to show you how I have set the canvas and page tab url settings

Comment: @dormisher, just checked your app on my page and updated answer with conclusions.

Comment: jesus your right! when I changed browsed to it using https it worked! thanks a lot.